# What's the difference between “crisscross" and “cross"?

Tags: difference

I read [the following caption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darjeeling#/media/File:Darjeeling_Himalayan_Railway.jpg):

> The narrow gauge train often crisscrosses the street

[image]

What's the difference between “crisscross" and  “cross" this context?

Comment: That is written by a non-native speaker. A train cannot crisscross a street. His name is given when you click through. He is probably Indian or Pakistani.

Comment: No, there is no typo or inversion. This is a no-go for crisscross. A person crisscrosses the street to see shops on either side of it.

Comment: @Lambie It looks like that train is crisscrossing the street to me. It's starting one one side of the road, it goes to the other side, and probably crosses back over to go along the original side of the road.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: "narrow-gauge train" is the correct word order for describing a train that runs on tracks that aren't very far apart.  ("narrow gauge" is adjective + noun.)  Narrow train gauge would be nonsense, it's the gauge that's narrow, not the train.  (Notice how far the train sticks out past the tracks, unlike on a normal railroad where the wheels are near the sides.  A train like that here could run over people's feed with pedestrian crowds right up against a moving train, like I suspect might happen wherever this is.)

Comment: Of course, if the train tracks *actually* crisscrossed across the street, i.e. were winding back and forth, there'd be no way for cars to pass if the train was long.  I'm not familiar with "street running" trains like this; in North America tracks might cross a street at an angle other than 90 degrees, but not wind along a street, other than trolley cars that have a lane and stick to it.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks good point I'll remove the erroneous comment.

Comment: @PeterCordes No train can move forward in a crisscross  pattern as crisscrossing requires 90 degree angles and trains do not turn at 90 angles. In my view, only people, metaphorically, and design patterns do any crisscrossing.

Comment: @nick012000 Here we go again, playing this insufferable game in these forums. Here's the thing: That train could be said to be snaking down the street. If you say crisscrossing, you simply do not understand that crisscrossing involves 90 degree angles....

Comment: @Lambie Thanks for your explanations. From what I have read, you're correct on the fact that crisscross involves straight lines (at least, stricto sensu), but I couldn't find a source mentioning the 90-degree angle:  [Must lines form 90-degree angles to be referred to as a crisscross pattern?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/285586/3023)

Comment: They are intersecting straight lines. The 90 degrees was in reference to a turn for a train.  If you read my answer, I don't say 90 degrees. Trains can pivot on an axis 90 degrees. That's all.

Comment: I agree with others that a train cannot possibly crisscross a road. Train *tracks* could crisscross a road, though I've never seen this. Properly, crisscrossing refers to the kind of pattern that the wooden slats of a trellis make. They don't have to meet at 90 degrees, but they form straight lines meeting at angles. Dictionaries often write things like "a pattern of crossed lines" or some such without explaining what pattern is meant, just as dictionaries don't define very precisely what an "elephant seal" is and so on.

Comment: Crisscrossing does not require 90 degree angles. The word as it is really used in English makes no statement about a specific geometric angle.

Comment: @Lambie What makes you think that someone called Michael Janich who was born in Germany (and whose full bio you clicked through) would be Indian or Pakistani, and for that matter, what makes you so sure that an Indian or Pakistani can't be native to a country that speaks English?

Comment: @HashimAziz When I originally saw the name, it looked like it might be Indian. It's no big deal. The point is, the writer is non-native. Now confirmed by you as German. So, there it is. It was: Mjanich. How could I know? I guess now I would say Hungarian or something.

Comment: I think there might not be a problem with the original text. This Wikipedia page has a map that suggests the train **does** crisscross a road: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darjeeling_Himalayan_Railway?wprov=sfti1

Comment: @Lambie You don't need right angles or intersections to crisscross a road. For instance, a heavily drunk person could "crisscross" a road by staggering down it, crossing repeatedly from one side to the other in an erratic fashion.

Comment: @ToddWilcox The train does not crisscross the road. It snakes across the road.

Comment: @nick012000 Anyone can crisscross a road, drunk or not. A train cannot. When a person crisscrosses a road, they go from one side to the other at an angle, going every farther down or up the road.  A train that crosses OVER a road is not crisscrossing it. even if it looks like that Darjeeling Himalayan Railway's route. That train is snaking across a route., which is under it, so to speak.

Comment: @Lambie You say tomato, I say tomato...

Comment: @ToddWilcox When the going gets tough....

Comment: @nick012000 Even if staggering, that person would still be subject to a right angle.

Answer (score 10):

From [Strongdar](https://www.reddit.com/user/Strongdar) on [Reddit](https://redd.it/nnxe9b):

> In that context, crisscross would tell you that it crosses the street repeatedly, in a back and forth sort of manner. Cross would just mean it goes over the street once.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of confusion in the answers and comments: the definition here for *crisscross* is correct, but the word is (almost certainly) being used incorrectly in the context. I'd say that *crisscross* is a nice example of a frequentative English verb. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequentative

Comment: @dbmag9  "the word is (almost certainly) being used incorrectly in the context. " -> see this comment: "This Wikipedia page has a map that suggests the train **does** crisscross a road: [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darjeeling\_Himalayan\_Railway?wprov=sfti1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darjeeling_Himalayan_Railway?wprov=sfti1) – [Todd Wilcox](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/21766/todd-wilcox "967 reputation")

Comment: No, it does not crisscross a road. It snakes across the road.

Answer (score 4):

> criss·cross
> /ˈkriskrôs/
>
> noun
> **a pattern of intersecting straight lines or paths.**
> "the crisscross of wrinkles on his face"

Oxford Dictionaries via Google

If you crisscross a street, you create an abstract pattern of intersecting straight lines as you go across and then return to the same side, several times.

Cross is just once; She crossed the street.

She crisscrossed the street. = She went back and forth several times across the street.

XXXXXX
XXXXXX

If you remove the white space between those two lines of x's, that is a crisscross pattern.

Comment: This is a noun. Oddly the verb used in the original question doesn't carry the "straight" connotation.

Comment: @solublefish crisscross is an adjective or verb. Not a noun. usually.

Comment: Your quote from Oxford literally labels it a noun. I agree this is not the usual usage.

Answer (score 0):

1. Bro so I am from Gulfport MS 26 year old Bryan Farmer. I thought criss cross was when you sit down folding your legs. I learn that it is actually cross cross and I've been hypnotized by toads. Also criss cross is when you repeatedly walk or travel an areas completely basically more than twice. But to cross something is to go with or around. Sometimes against. Big stuff to think about.

Comment: No, you really do sit [**criss**-cross (applesauce)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/criss-cross_applesauce) (this isn't really related to the question at hand, however).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).