# Must lines form 90-degree angles to be referred to as a crisscross pattern?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I [read on ELL SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/285540/whats-the-difference-between-crisscross-and-cross?noredirect=1#comment533691_285540):

> crisscrossing involves 90 degree angles. – [Lambie](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/33113/lambie)[5 mins ago](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/285540/whats-the-difference-between-crisscross-and-cross?noredirect=1#comment533691_285540)

However, I couldn't find any dictionary mentioning the angle. E.g., [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/criss-cross) and [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crisscross) don't mention any constraint on the angle the lines form. When searching for [crisscross arrows](https://www.shutterstock.com/search/criss+cross+arrows), I see different angles as well.

[image]

Must lines form 90-degree angles to be referred to as a crisscross pattern?

Comment: The expression derives from 'Christ's cross', which does of course mean two beams at right angles; but the meaning has evolved to refer to any pattern of intersecting lines.

Comment: Oh please. I was talking about how trains turn. Thanks for taking my comments out of context.

Comment: @Lambie did you mean train would turn with a 90-degree angle  if rails follow a crisscross pattern?

Comment: I will not play this game with you. Of course, a damn train cannot turn at a 90 degree angle. That's why they cannot crisscross a street. You seem to be gaslighting. See ya.

Comment: @Lambie "a damn train cannot turn at a 90 degree angle. That's why they cannot crisscross a street. " -> From my understanding, this means that crisscrossing involves 90 degree angles.  I'm just here to learn a foreign language.

Comment: **My answer** to the other question does not say 90 degree angle. So, do not misquote and remove that.

Comment: @Lambie  **your comment**  does say 90 degree angle, which is what I quoted.

Comment: I explained what I meant RE trains. There are turns at 90 degrees. A car could make a 90 degree turn. A person can make a 90 degree turn. Stop misquoting me. Train rails do not have a crisscross pattern. You are gaslighting, clearly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be described as 'criss cross' a pattern only needs to consist of lines that cross each other, at any angle.

[image]